# Auto Increment Problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Using SQL Server

Table1

```
ID Name

001 Raja
002 Ravi
003 Suresh
004 Kamal
...
```

I need to create a new table and make a identity for each column

Tried query

```
insert into table2 
  select * from table1
```

Expected output

```
S.No ID Name

1 001 Raja
2 002 Ravi
3 003 Suresh
4 004 Kamal
...
```

I create the new table and made the S.No column is identity in the table.  It is creating the identity number for each row, then I delete all the row, again inserted, but identity is created from last row next number onwards.

Example

```
S.No ID Name

    1 001 Raja
    2 002 Ravi
    3 003 Suresh
    4 004 Kamal
    ...
```

Delete all the rows, again I inserted.

```
S.No ID Name

    5 001 Raja
    6 002 Ravi
    7 003 Suresh
    8 004 Kamal
    ...
```

Expected output

Identity should start from number 1 onwards whenever I am deleting all the rows from the table.

Need query help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not how identity works. Deleting stuff won't reset the identity field. You have to reseed it:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ( ‘databasename.dbo.yourtable’,RESEED, 0) -- will start from 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, How to write a delete with your mentioned query.  Currently i am writing delete * from table2, so here how can i insert your mentioned query.

Comment: @Gopal: you will need to have a query that contains **two statements** - first your `delete * from table2` and next `DBCC CHECKIDENT(....., RESEED, 0)` - one statement after the other

Comment: @marc_s yes, you will. I thought the reseeding part was harder so I only mentioned that.

Answer (score 2):

Or just truncate the table? That will reset the primary key, too.
(marc_s: actually, it's the **IDENTITY** value that it's resetting)

```
TRUNCATE TABLE tablename
```

Comment: Truncate table means it will delete the table datas or table

Comment: Not the table, just the data - but that's what you want isn't it? Deleting the data and reset the auto increment counter?

Comment: TRUNCATE isn't really "resetting the primary key" - what it's resetting is the IDENTITY counter - added a comment to your post to clarify

Answer (score 0):

If you want S.No column has auto increment and that's value has (Maximum No + 1),

so you can create a scalar function to find that value and set the column DefaultValue to this function and set **identity to false**.

Look this sample:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[getmaxno]()
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ResultVar int
    SELECT @ResultVar = MAX(no)+1 from dbo.table_1
    RETURN @ResultVar
END

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table_1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Table_1_no]  DEFAULT ([dbo].[getmaxno]()) FOR [no]
```